# Keil uvision5. A51 how properly assign labels to and address bits in memory

Tags: keil

I want to assign labels to bits in variables stored in memory:

```
mem equ 21h ;
y1:  bit   mem.0  ;
y2:  bit    mem.1
x1: bit mem.2
```

So, I could do something like this:

```
mov r1, #0
mov c, y1
cpl c
orl c, y2
anl c, y1
anl c, /x1
```

But when I do this the compiler throws an error. So I am forced to address the bits like this:

```
mov r1, #0
mov c, mem.1
cpl c
orl c, mem.2
anl c, mem.1
anl c, /mem.0
```

And the code becomes less readable. Is there a way to fix it?
P.S. I am using ADuC842 device.

Comment: What's the error that is thrown?

Comment: Syntax error, but according to a book I got that idea from, it should be alright.